# Is it possible to schedule Quartz threads to run each second?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to have Java Quartz threads run each second, or even by milliseconds? It seems like they can only run by the minute and nothing less.

Comment: how come it seems like that? Would you show the piece of code that you think is impossible to make work with seconds?

Comment: people, that's why it seemed like that :P. I wasn't familiar with the docs and now I see you can define one to run each second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can make them run every second.

Take a look at [TriggerUtils.makeSecondlyTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.0/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html#makeSecondlyTrigger%28%29):

> Make a trigger that will fire every
>   second, indefinitely.

Or use a [CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html):

```
new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","group","* * * * * ?"); //fire at every second daily
```

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

You need to go for [Simple Trigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson05.html)

> trigger that fires immediately, then repeats every X mills, forever

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                                            null,
                                            new Date(),
                                            null,
                                            SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY,
                                            X);
```

Note: Where X is long type,
for example  : if X=1000L then per second